# reCaptcha v3 React invisible component

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

So i am using the react-recaptcha-v3 component in my react app, and it renders an invisible recaptcha on my page. Is there any way to trigger the challenge? I want to see how it would look

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to force it in the library itself, but maybe you can manually spam your form for a while?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem trying to trigger the captcha. I read somewhere that it uses the movement of the mouse to segregate bot behaviour or not.

Try using the mouse keys on your computer to scroll the page. Use `Left-Alt + Left-Shift + NumLock` to move the mouse and scroll a few times. This should trigger the image reCaptcha test. It  worked for me.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I shall try this when i get home tonight and let you know if it it worked.